# Error in UseMethod("accuracy") : no applicable method for 'accuracy' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"

Tags: r, regression, rpart

i was trying to predict price for used car data in r. i have done all the preprocessing and divided the data into training and test set. here i am using regression tree. when i was trying to get accuracy i got this error.

```
library(rpart)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
dput(head(train.df, 5))

reg_tree <- rpart(price ~ ., 
            data = train.df,
            method = "anova", minbucket = 1, maxdepth = 30, cp = 0.001)

accuracy(predict(reg_tree, train.df), train.df$price)
```

```
structure(list(price = 33990, year = 2018L, manufacturer = structure(1L, .Label = c("acura", 
"alfa-romeo", "aston-martin", "audi", "bmw", "buick", "cadillac", 
"chevrolet", "chrysler", "datsun", "dodge", "ferrari", "fiat", 
"ford", "gmc", "harley-davidson", "honda", "hyundai", "infiniti", 
"jaguar", "jeep", "kia", "land rover", "lexus", "lincoln", "mazda", 
"mercedes-benz", "mercury", "mini", "mitsubishi", "nissan", "pontiac", 
"porsche", "ram", "rover", "saturn", "subaru", "tesla", "toyota", 
"volkswagen", "volvo"), class = "factor"), condition = structure(4L, .Label = c("excellent", 
"fair", "good", "like new", "new", "salvage"), class = "factor"), 
    cylinders = structure(6L, .Label = c("10 cylinders", "12 cylinders", 
    "3 cylinders", "4 cylinders", "5 cylinders", "6 cylinders", 
    "8 cylinders", "other"), class = "factor"), fuel = structure(3L, .Label = c("diesel", 
    "electric", "gas", "hybrid", "other"), class = "factor"), 
    odometer = 22267, title_status = structure(1L, .Label = c("clean", 
    "lien", "missing", "parts only", "rebuilt", "salvage"), class = "factor"), 
    transmission = structure(1L, .Label = c("automatic", "manual", 
    "other"), class = "factor"), drive = structure(2L, .Label = c("4wd", 
    "fwd", "rwd"), class = "factor"), size = structure(3L, .Label = c("compact", 
    "full-size", "mid-size", "sub-compact"), class = "factor"), 
    type = structure(4L, .Label = c("bus", "convertible", "coupe", 
    "hatchback", "mini-van", "offroad", "other", "pickup", "sedan", 
    "SUV", "truck", "van", "wagon"), class = "factor"), paint_color = structure(10L, .Label = c("black", 
    "blue", "brown", "custom", "green", "grey", "orange", "purple", 
    "red", "silver", "white", "yellow"), class = "factor")), row.names = 31113L, class = "data.frame")


Error in UseMethod("accuracy") : 
  no applicable method for 'accuracy' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

could anyone please help me in this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(train.df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(train.df, 20))`. And please load the packages you are using with calls to `library()` in the beginning of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I don't know which package the `accuracy` function comes from (maybe `MLmetrics::Accuracy`??), however, the error is due to the metric you use with respect to the type of the problem: accuracy is used in a classification problem, where the outcome is typically a `factor` that can only have certain values (discrete variable). Here you are fitting a regression model, due to the class of your outcome (`numeric`). The car's price can vary continuously within a certain range. So, for the regression problem, one of the most used metrics to evaluate the model performance is the root mean square error (RMSE). The `RMSE` function is implemented in the `caret` package. Here I post an example with the in-built dataset `cars.test.frame` from the package `rpart:

```
library(rpart)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(caret)

data("car.test.frame")
ind <- createDataPartition(car.test.frame$Price,p=.8,list=F)
train.df <- car.test.frame[ind,]
test.df <- car.test.frame[-ind,]

reg_tree <- rpart(Price ~ ., 
                  data = train.df,
                  method = "anova", minbucket = 1, maxdepth = 30, cp = 0.001)



rmse <- RMSE(predict(reg_tree, test.df), test.df$Price)
rmse_perc <- rmse/mean(test.df$Price)*100
```

the RMSE can be reported as a percentage of the average car price. You can also implement your own `rmse` function thanks to its ease of calculation:

```
rmse <- function (y_pred, y_true) 
{
  RMSE <- sqrt(mean((y_true - y_pred)^2))
  return(RMSE)
}
```

However, the `rmse` function above is identical to the `RMSE` of the `caret` package

Answer (score -2):

just use

```
library(forecast)
```

and it will work!